# How to set a Custom Variable (NOT DIMENSION) in Google Analytics through GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So we've managed to get Custom Dimensions working, but we need Custom Variables as well (Audience > Custom > Custom Variables)

The problem is: we use GTM and have no idea how to implement these with GTM rather than the tutorial provided by Google here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom variables are a legacy thing and not part of Universal Analytics (in part I would guess because they rely on some parts in the client-side tracking code that is no longer part of UA - session- and user scoped variables were persisted via the client side code in legacy Google Analytics, and the UA code does not really calculate any values in the client - this has all moved to the server side).

So at this point your only option to use custom variables would be to integrate legacy GA code via a custom HTML tag, which would not be compatible with many UA features.

If you need the client-side persistence of custom variables (there used to be a number of hacks that relied on reading the values on the client side) you would still need to switch to custiom dimensions and write your own client-side logic to store the values you send.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to implement them anymore unfortunately, they are deprecated.

More information [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4457764?hl=en)